# To use a group of views with different templates for the same actions in controller in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, routes, view

I have two layouts for my application, and I need to use a group of views for one of those templates (for same controller actions)

I don’t want to touch each action on the controllers specifying the view to use with render.

My views looks like:

```
* /Views/controller_abc/new.erb
* /Views/alternative_template/controller_abc/new.erb
```

Comment: Please note I would like to do this only once, not modifying render in all controllers

Comment: As I understand you want to use `controller_abc/new.erb` for one layout and `alternative_template/controller_abc/new.erb` for another one, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use prepend_view_path, in your `ApplicationController`

```
before_filter :set_view_path

def set_view_path
    prepend_view_path "#{Rails.root}/app/views/alternative_template"
end
```